# Calculating time using modulus with possible rounding errors

Tags: c#, string-formatting, func, livecharts

I receive a time value in seconds from a database and I want to calculate this to a readable time. These are total active times for messages, so I don't have to take any leap years into account.

I'm calculating times from seconds that can be over 24 hours so `hhh:mm:ss`. I use this to format the lables on a chart from Live Charts. In my code I use the following code to calculate it:

```
public Func<double, string> Formatter { get; set; }

Formatter = value => (((value - (value % 3600)) / 3600) + ":" + (((value % 3600) - (value % 60)) / 60) + ":" + (value % 60));
```

This works fine but sometimes results in:

```
222:3:4
```

but what I want is:

```
222:03:04
```

I've found the following code to make a `string.Format` but I don't know how I can apply this when I'm using `Func<>`:

```
static string Method1(int secs)
{
    int hours = secs / 3600;
    int mins = (secs % 3600) / 60;
    secs = secs % 60;
    return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", hours, mins, secs);
}
```

How can I apply this `string.Format` when I'm using `public Func<double, string>` to calculate the times over 24 hours long.

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of issues if you use DateTime/TimeSpan for anything time or date related.  Then you don't have to worry about leap years/leap seconds etc.

Comment: @Neil, I know, in this case I don't have to take leap years into account. I have editted my question to make this clear.

Comment: `(value - (value % 3600)) / 3600` would be more efficiently done as `(int)(value / 3600)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.Format within you `public Func<double, string>`, just apply the values as parameters rather than a single string:

```
Formatter = value => string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", (int)(value - (value % 3600)) / 3600, (int)((value % 3600) - (value % 60)) / 60, (int)value % 60);
```

Alternatively, as already stated, it's probably better to use the built in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the standard TimeSpan formatters.  Probably 'g':

```
static string Method1(int secs)
{
    var ts = new TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
    return ts.Format('g');
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7.2